# Python Win 3.6.0 x64 issue, missing qt designer exe after pip3 install pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer, python-3.6

I'm a Python newbie and trying to start my first application and am struggling to workout how to use Qt Designer with pyQT5.

I've been using the next command which installs pyqt5.7.1:

```
pip3 install pyqt5
```

After the install, I have a

```
C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin\Qt5Designer.dll
```

file but no Qt Designer exe as far as i can tell.

id really appreciate the help if anyone has any idea what i'm missing? Do I have to install the full Qt5 framework to be able to use Qt Designer and pyQT5?

Thanks

Pete

Comment: I have the same problem. Are we forced to use Qt Creator?

Comment: install qt. the thing you install with pip is the python binding.

Answer (score 5):

On `WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2Qt5` I run:

```
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

installs at:

```
WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools\designer.exe
```

Starts ok!

Comment: Thanks! Everything installed correctly... but I couldn't find the .EXE. Thought I was going crazy. Based on your comment I decided to do a simple search of my folders.... and alas... there it was!

Comment: On Windows, I use this little tool called "Everything". I heartily recommend it.You have a zillion options on what to index on your hard drive, and keeps a database continuously updated in the background for almost instantaneous global searches... For those cases like this when we have to find "lost" files...

Answer (score 3):

At some point during the 3.5 version of Python QT Designer was dropped from the pyqt5 package, and then picked up by the pyqt5_tools package. Unfortunately the tools package is not available for Python 3.6 (at least so far).

You can download the version 3.5 32-bit or 64-bit pyqt5_tools package from pypi.python.org:

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqt5-tools/5.7.dev9
```

Next open the wheel package you downloaded with a zip tool and copy the designer folder and contents to a convenient location. Designer and all the needed dependencies are in this folder. Good luck.

Comment: See my answer below you can now `pip install pyqt5-tools`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution On Windows

1. `pip3 install pyqt5-tools`
2. open
   `C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools\designer`
   and copy all the content to
   `C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin`,
   don't overwrite files with the same file name!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to install QT Designer is as follows:

1. Install latest QT (I'm using 5.8) from [QT main site](https://www.qt.io/)
2. Make sure you include "Qt 5.8 MinGW" component
3. QT Designer will be installed in `C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\designer.exe`
4. Note that the executable is named "designer.exe"