# Could not start Qt-designer

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

On windows7 64bits, I just installed Eric6 in this way :

- python -m pip install pyqt5
- python -m pip install QScintilla
- install.py

I tried to follow their first tutorial LogParser on https://eric-ide.python-projects.org/tutorials/LogParser/chap2.html

When coming to create LogParser.ui I get the following error :

Could not start Qt-designer
Ensure that it is available as ...Python36\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin\designer.exe

When checking there is a folder: C:\Users\Gustav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin
But its not containg any exe file

Any help would be nice !

Comment: try with this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.5.1/

Comment: My solution On Windows https://stackoverflow.com/a/47255886/1485853

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install QT Designer as follows (as a stand-alone application, not using Eric IDE):

1. Install latest QT (I'm using 5.8) from [QT main site](https://www.qt.io/)
2. Make sure you include "Qt 5.8 MinGW" component
3. QT Designer will be installed in `C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\designer.exe`
4. Note that the executable is named "designer.exe"