# Why does Mac say "cannot execute binary file" for QtDesigner in PyQt5 for Python3.6?

Tags: macos, pyqt5, qt-designer, python-3.6

I added PyQt5 to the Python3.6 installation on my iMac running Sierra 10.12.4 in a Terminal window with:

```
$pip3 PyQt5
```

Then I tried to run QtDesigner. It failed as follows:

```
$cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtDesigner.framework/Versions/5
$./QtDesigner
-bash: ./QtDesigner: cannot execute binary file
```

The file description is:

```
$file QtDesigner
QtDesigner: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

I was pretty sure my iMac is a 64 bit machine but just to check:

```
file /usr/bin/mail
/usr/bin/mail: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Any ideas why QtDesigner won't run?

Comment: The error message suggests that you're mistakenly passing a _binary_ to `bash` for execution, as if it were a _shell script_.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to run `QtDesigner.so`? This is a library file, and cannot be executed directly. It looks like [Qt Designer is no longer part of the `PyQt5` package](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42013189/45375).

Comment: You're right. I didn't realize "dynamically linked shared libraries" aren't executable. I downloaded Qt 5.8 and all is well now. Thanks for your help.